# JavaScript errors after multiple onmouseover calls

Tags: javascript, html, function

```js
function langPicker(buttonid) {
  animationForwarder('sectionlang1', 'sectionlang2', 'anim-switchByFadeIn-lang', 100)
  setTimeout(langTextChange, 625, buttonid);
}

function langTextChange(buttonid) {
  const subject1 = document.getElementById('sectionlang1');
  const subject2 = document.getElementById('sectionlang2');
  if (buttonid == 'cpp') {
    subject1.textContent = 'C++';
    subject2.textContent = 'C++ is one of the most renowned programming languages in the world';
  }
}

function anFrwdDoubleExec(identifier, identifier2, identifier3, identifier4, anim_id, wait_time, anim_id2, wait_time2, secondExecutionWaitTime) {
  animationForwarder(identifier, identifier2, anim_id, wait_time);
  setTimeout(() => {
    animationForwarder(identifier3, identifier4, anim_id2, wait_time2)
  }, secondExecutionWaitTime);
}

function animationForwarder(identifier, identifier2, anim_id, wait_time) {
  document.getElementById(identifier).classList.add(anim_id);
  if (identifier2 != 'skip') {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById(identifier2).classList.add(anim_id)
    }, wait_time);
  }
}
```

```css
.nonstandard-draft {
  max-width: 15vw;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1.7vw;
  right: 1.7vw;
}

.nonstandard-draft-head {
  font-size: 1.7vw;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Belanosima;
  margin: 0 0 1.2vw 0;
}

.nonstandard-draft-data {
  font-family: Belanosima;
  font-size: 1vw;
  white-space: pre-line;
  color: #0d8569;
  filter: drop-shadow(0.1vw 0.1vw 0.2vw black);
}

.grd-draft1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #f269e0, #ff5d9a, #ff864b, #ffbd00, #a8eb12);
  filter: drop-shadow(0vw 0vw 0.1vw #ff864b);
}

.grd-draft2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #8f00ff, #007aff, #0091ef, #009994, #009950);
  filter: drop-shadow(0vw 0vw 0.1vw #0091ef);
}

.w-100p {
  width: 100%;
}

.w-97p {
  width: 97%;
}

.w-14p75 {
  width: 14.75vw;
}

.w-9p5 {
  width: 9.5vw;
}

.h-100p {
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  background-image: url('../RESOURCES/bgs/bg12.gif');
  height: 100vh;
}

.fx {
  display: flex;
}

.fx-jc-spb {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.fx-ai-c {
  align-items: center;
}

.fx-jc-c {
  justify-content: center;
}

.fx-dir-c {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mg-none {
  margin: 0;
}

#headertext {
  width: 0vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.headertexttransformed {
  width: 48.5709375vw !important;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.b-sh-def {
  box-shadow: 0vw 0vw 0.3vw grey;
}

.bgs-full {
  background-size: 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
}

.headerimage {
  width: 12vw;
  margin-right: 3.25vw;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

.headergradienttext {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 3vw;
}

.ff-raleway {
  font-family: Raleway;
}

.grd-firsth1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #000000, #202020, #3a3a3a, #565656, #747474);
  filter: drop-shadow(0.1vw 0.1vw 0.01vw #3a3a3a);
}

.grd-sech1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #00e377, #00e395, #00e2af, #00e1c3, #00ded3);
  filter: drop-shadow(0.1vw 0.1vw 0.01vw #00e377);
}

.gradient-text {
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -o-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -o-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.fc-violet {
  color: blueviolet;
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  top: 1vw;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 10vw;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dp-none {
  display: none;
}

.wh-animelem-1 {
  width: 1.5vw;
  height: 1.5vw;
}

.wh-animelem-1-addr-1 {
  top: -2vw;
  left: -2vw;
}

.wh-animelem-1-addr-2 {
  bottom: -2vw;
  right: -2vw;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.headercontainer {
  margin: 3.25vw;
}

.fsz-1 {
  font-size: 1vw;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  33.3% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  66.6% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  99.9% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.abm-section {
  height: 74vh;
  padding: 10vh 0;
}

.bs-bb {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.anim-1 {
  animation: anim1 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.nest-subsection {
  width: 80vw;
  max-width: 1250px;
}

.general-subsection {
  max-height: calc(70vh - 80px);
}

.add-text-subsection {
  font-family: Belanosima;
}

.t-ss-heading {
  font-size: 48px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

.t-ss-paragraph {
  font-size: 34px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0.2vw 0.2vw 0.1vw #a6a6a6);
}

.t-ss-paragraph-modabm {
  max-width: 671.438px;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.anim-blink {
  animation: blink 1.25s infinite;
}

.pfp {
  height: 340px;
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 15%;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

@keyframes fadeInTR {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-75px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.anim-fadeintr {
  animation: fadeInTR 0.75s ease-out forwards;
}

.scroll-alternative {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scroll-alternative::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.op-0 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.border {
  height: 40px;
  background: url('../RESOURCES/SHWHP_RES/greeceborder.png'), white;
  background-size: contain;
}

.abm-bgp {
  background: url('../RESOURCES/SHWHP_RES/bg-content/bg-master.png'), white;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom left;
}

.longsec-child-preset {
  height: 70vh;
  color: #f3f3f3;
}

.general-heading {
  font-size: 54px;
}

.add-lang-paragraph {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

@keyframes fadeInTB {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.anim-fadeintb {
  animation: fadeInTB 0.75s cubic-bezier(.2, 1, 1, 1) forwards;
}

.bg-long {
  background-image: url('../RESOURCES/bgs/bg14.jpg');
}

.longer-subsection {
  max-height: 100%;
}

.lang-pick {
  width: 225px;
  height: 225px;
  padding: 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.lang-pick-opt {
  width: 94px;
  height: 94px;
  margin: 9.25px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.cpp {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #5ffbf1, #64fcec, #69fde7, #6ffde1, #76fedc, #83fed7, #8fffd3, #9affcf, #abffcd, #baffcc, #c7ffcc, #d3ffce);
}

.cpp::before {
  content: '';
  width: 71.27659574468085%;
  height: 6px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  background-color: #08fcbc;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in;
}

.lang-pick:hover .cpp::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out;
}

.cpp::after {
  content: '';
  width: 6px;
  height: 71.27659574468085%;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  background-color: #08fcbc;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in;
}

.lang-pick:hover .cpp::after {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out;
}

.html {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #e28ef6, #d884f4, #ce7af2, #c470f0, #b867ef, #af66ef, #a564f0, #9b63f0, #9168f2, #876df4, #7d72f5, #7376f5);
}

.html::before {
  content: '';
  width: 71.27659574468085%;
  height: 6px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  background-color: #08fcbc;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in;
}

.lang-pick:hover .html::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out;
}

.html::after {
  content: '';
  width: 6px;
  height: 71.27659574468085%;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  background-color: #08fcbc;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in;
}

.lang-pick:hover .html::after {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out;
}

.css {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #5ffbf1, #46eefa, #41dfff, #52cffe, #69bff8, #79b3f4, #8aa7ec, #9a9ae1, #aa8fd8, #ba83ca, #c777b9, #d16ba5);
}

.css::before {
  content: '';
  width: 71.27659574468085%;
  height: 6px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  background-color: #08fcbc;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in;
}

.lang-pick:hover .css::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out;
}

.css::after {
  content: '';
  width: 6px;
  height: 71.27659574468085%;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  background-color: #08fcbc;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in;
}

.lang-pick:hover .css::after {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out;
}

.js {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #b1ff00, #90ff4e, #6eff76, #4dff97, #2affb4, #4bf6a6, #5eee98, #6ce58c, #8fcf5b, #a9b72f, #be9c05, #ce7e00);
}

.js::before {
  content: '';
  width: 71.27659574468085%;
  height: 6px;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  background-color: #08fcbc;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out;
}

.lang-pick:hover .js::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out;
}

.js::after {
  content: '';
  width: 6px;
  height: 71.27659574468085%;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: -20px;
  background-color: #08fcbc;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out;
}

.lang-pick:hover .js::after {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transform-origin: bottom;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out;
}

.cur-sel {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.whp-icon {
  width: 74%;
  height: 74%;
  transition: all 0.15s;
}

.whp-icon:hover {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  transition: all 0.15s;
}

.pos-abs {
  position: absolute;
}

.p-ab-center {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.pos-rel {
  position: relative;
}

.anim-switchByFadeIn-lang {
  animation: switchByFadeIn-lang 1.25s ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes switchByFadeIn-lang {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(75px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50.001% {
    transform: translateX(-150px);
  }
  100.001% {
    transform: translateX(75px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section onmouseover="anFrwdDoubleExec('sectionlang1', 'sectionlang2', 'slash1-lang', 'slash2-lang', 'anim-fadeintb', 250, 'anim-blink', 100, 0)" class="longsec-child-preset w-100p fx fx-jc-c fx-ai-c fx-dir-c">
  <div class="nest-subsection fx fx-jc-spb fx-ai-c">
    <div class="longer-subsection add-text-subsection fx-dir-c bs-bb">
      <h1 id="sectionlang1" class="mg-none general-heading underline-marker op-0"><span id="slash1-lang">/</span><span id="slash2-lang">/</span> Languages: the keys</h1>
      <p id="sectionlang2" class="t-ss-paragraph t-ss-paragraph-modabm add-lang-paragraph ff-raleway mg-none op-0">Languages serve as my trump cards: they are like limbs for every programmer. And I am no exception! Here you can review the aforementioned.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="lang-pick fx">
      <div onclick="langPicker('cpp')" class="lang-pick-opt bgs-full cpp pos-rel cur-sel">
        <img src="RESOURCES/SHWHP_RES/cpp_b&w.png" class="whp-icon pos-abs p-ab-center" alt="C++">
      </div>
      <div class="lang-pick-opt bgs-full html pos-rel cur-sel">
        <img src="RESOURCES/SHWHP_RES/html_b&w.png" class="whp-icon pos-abs p-ab-center" alt="HTML">
      </div>
      <div class="lang-pick-opt bgs-full css pos-rel cur-sel">
        <img src="RESOURCES/SHWHP_RES/css_b&w.png" class="whp-icon pos-abs p-ab-center" alt="CSS">
      </div>
      <div class="lang-pick-opt bgs-full js pos-rel cur-sel">
        <img src="RESOURCES/SHWHP_RES/js_b&w.png" class="whp-icon pos-abs p-ab-center" alt="JS">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Basically, I wanted to share with you a question: why the js breaks after multiple onmouseover calls over an element? The code snippet's below to ease the error's identification (log also below).

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

What I had tried before posting this:

1. Checking for any mistakes in the values;
2. Analyzing the function body;
3. Asking GPT.

No results for me.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: @LightningMcQueen Sorry, I was in the process whilst you were writing this comment

Comment: `document.getElementById(...) is null`, what's `identifier` at all?

Comment: @LightningMcQueen the animationForwarder is supposed to add animations to elements while their parent container is hovered on.  Could you tell me exactly when the identifier's null?

Comment: When you hover the "C++" element `TypeError: can't access property \"classList\", document.getElementById(...) is null`, this error happens because there's no such element as "identifier".

Comment: @LightningMcQueen it seems like it's looking for "slash1-lang" but it's hard to tell why. The code is extremely confusing.

Comment: OK, when the code changes the `.textContent` it blows away that hazy background text that comes from those `<span>` elements in the `<h1>` contents. That's the problem. Once that content is deleted, the code can no longer find "slash1-lang" on the page, because it is not on the page.

Comment: Specifically in the `langTextChange()` function. Setting `.textContent` for the "sectionlang1" `<h1>` tag removes all content before setting the new content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you do:

```
    subject1.textContent = 'C++';
    subject2.textContent = 'C++ is one of the most renowned programming languages in the world';
```

`subject1` is the `<h1 id="sectionlang1"` element. This contains `<span id="slash1-lang">` and `<span id="slash2-lang">`. When you replace the `<h1>` contents, the `<span>` is removed. So when you later call

```
anFrwdDoubleExec('sectionlang1', 'sectionlang2', 'slash1-lang', 'slash2-lang', 'anim-fadeintb', 250, 'anim-blink', 100, 0)
```

it tries to set the class of `slash1-lang` and `slash2-lang`, but they no longer exist so you get an error.

I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish by replacing the contents of these elements. If you just want to prevent the error, check whether `document.getElementById()` returns anything. So replace

```
document.getElementById(identifier).classList.add(anim_id);
```

with

```
let el = document.getElementById(identifier);
if (el) {
    el.classList.add(anim_id);
}
```